# How to find similar wiki pages with n-gram?

Tags: distance, similarity, n-gram, euclidean-distance

Let's suppose there's a wiki, and for every wiki page I'd like to show a widget - with the list of similar pages.

It could be done in two steps:

**Step 1** - convert each page into feature vector with NGram (there are better ways to do so, for example using word2vec, but I'd like to keep the approach simple to better understand the core concepts).

And here's the first problem - the **dimension of the feature vector will be huge**. Let's say we'll be using NGram = 3 and with only `a-z` symbols, there are 26 letters, so the dimensionality of the feature vector will be 26 * 26 * 26 = 17576

**What are the simple way to handle huge dimensionality of the feature vector?** (there are complex ways to solve that, for example word2vec uses very smart approach, but I really would like to use something simpler to implement it and get the feeling how it works).

**Step 2** - we have a bunch of vectors - each for every page in a N-dimensional vector space. Now we need to **find similar vectors**, again there are multiple ways to define similarity, I'd like to use **Euclidean distance**.

What are the efficient way to get `k` closest vectors for the given vector X? We can use brute-force and compare vector X with every other vector, but it's inefficient. Is there a better way?